# How to copy files from one folder to multiple other folders using a dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary, copy

I have a dictionary of the whole file path and the path to it's folder destination in a dictionary. Is there some method to use it to copy the files into the folder their paired with in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method, but a simple for-loop and shutil will get the job done.

```
import shutil

files = {"source/path": "move/to"} # your dict

for source, move in files.items():
    shutil.copyfile(source, f"dir/{move}") # dir/ is the directory your paths are in
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand if you have two separate dictionnaries/arrays for the source and destination, but the setup are pretty similar.

I would parse each file, and for each one parse each directory to then apply a file copying operation.

For the copying we can use the [`shutil` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) which propose some high-level file methods.

Assuming your setup is :

```
files = ["/path/to/first/file", "/path/to/second/file" ...]
directories = ["/path/to/first/destination/", "/path/to/second/destination/" ...]
```

The copy code would be :

```
for file in files :
    for path in directories:
        shutil.copyfile(file, path)
```

Similarely if you have a dictionnary declared like this

```
dictionnary = {"/file/path" : "/file/destination"}
```

The code could be :

```
for file, path in dictionnary :
    shutil.copyfile(file, path)
```

If you have two separates dictionnaries the first one (with two arrays) should be pretty close to what you're searching.

Comment: The first nested for loop would copy every file to every possible destination, correct?

Comment: @YogeshThambidurai Yes ! That's the idea ! If you use a dictionnary with a simple structure it would be pretty easy to adapt this code to parse the dictionnary's keys and/or values.